# User profile requiring review/deletion

Tags: discussion, status-completed

https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/12054/fe3r

This profile description contains swearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an unregistered account and he's posted a complete non answer that also contained swearing.

I've destroyed the account.

It would be better just to flag one of their posts if you see something like this in the future.

Comment: I did flag the post, but I was also looking for a way to flag the user account itself.